# TeXShop and knitr

Tags: latex, knitr

I run LaTeX on a Mac using the TeXShop editor. I have now been trying to set up knitr with this system, but seem to be failing.

With R, I have installed the knitr package using `install.packages("knitr")`. To set up TeXShop, I have saved this script

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('$1')"
latexmk -pdf "${1%.*}"
```

shown [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/) as `~/library/TexShop/engines/Knitr.engine`.

Now I am trying to run it by opening TeXShop, select the `Knitr` engine from the dropdown menu, and execute [this script](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/002-minimal.Rnw) which is recommended [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/minimal/) "for absolute beginners". The script is saved as `test.Rnw` on the desktop.

However, nothing is happening, not even an error message. I am hoping there is this one thing that I should obviously do but failed to realize — e.g., include the path to R in the script. Any ideas?

Comment: Your workflow is bizarre: The whole point of the script is to invoke knitr *for you*, so why are you manually opening R and loading knitr? Those operations do nothing. The script, as posted, should work; you need to give more details for us to figure out what’s happening. In TeXShop, have you opened a knitr document? What’s its path? Is LaTeX set up in the paths that are used in the script (that’s the default)? Did you make the engine file executable?

Comment: Thanks! I agree it felt weird but I thought it was worth trying. Excluded that part from the question and added some information. Does this clarify?

Comment: These are the steps I have taken. If they did not make the script executable, I haven't done it. How would that work?